# Assembly program to write character from stack

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I am trying to write a test program in AT&T syntax assembly that pushes the ascii value of some characters to the stack, then prints them. My code is as follows:

```
.text
.global main
main:
    push $0
    push $10
    push $65
    mov $4,%eax
    mov $1,%ebx
    mov %esp,%ecx
    mov $3,%edx
    int $0x80

    mov $1,%eax
    int $0x80
```

What I would expect this program to do is push 0, 10, and 65 to the stack so that the stack is 65, 10, 0 (capital A, new-line, end of string). Set `eax` and `ebx` to the values for writing to stdout, and setting `ecx` to the stack pointer so that it writes what's on the stack, while `edx` is the length of what's on the stack(i.e. 3). When I run this, absolutely nothing happens. Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong and what is actually happening here?

Comment: `push` stores 4 bytes into memory (in 32 bit mode). You should thus see your letter `A` only. A single `push $0x0a41` should get you the line feed too. Note that `write()` or your terminal don't particularly care about a terminating zero, so just printing two bytes is enough.

Comment: With my initial code, or with the single push version you suggest, nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: Both work here as described. Run your code through `strace` then.

Comment: Run it in debugger, and check value of `rsp/esp` after each `push`, put it into question. If it moves by `8`, you are compiling this 32b linux API assembler source as 64b binary, which will not work, you will need to use `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`, and fix the arguments (`syscall` services are different). If you don't have debugger, just try to add `mov rax,rcx`, that should fail in 32b mode, but will compile in 64b). And you absolutely need debugger, and learn to work with it.

Comment: And in case you are compiling it by accident as 64b binary: check this answer, why it will not work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730/4271923

Comment: You need to revise your definition of "absolutely nothing".  Use `strace ./a.out` to see the `write()` and `exit()` system calls your process makes, and/or pipe into `hexdump -C` to see the bytes it writes to stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each `push` instruction pushes 4 bytes onto the stack. So, this is how the stack looks like before the `int 0x80`:

```
   ....
----------  (highest address)
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- <-- push $0
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x0A  | 
---------- <-- push $10
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x41  |
---------- <-- push $65 <-- ESP
```

However, at that moment you would like the stack to look like:

```
   ....
---------- 
|  0x00  |
---------- 
|  0x0A  |
---------- 
|  0x41  |
---------- <-- ESP
```

This can be achieved by replacing your `push` instructions by the following:

```
push $0x0a41
```

That is:

```
.text
.global main
main:
    push $0x0a41

    mov $4,%eax    ;system call write()
    mov $1,%ebx    ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov %esp,%ecx  ;string
    mov $3,%edx    ;length of the string
    int $0x80

    mov $1,%eax
    int $0x80
```

In the `edx` register you are already specifying the length of the string (i.e.: `3`), the *NUL* character is pointless (you are actually sending it to `stdout`).

Comment: Using that push statement and setting `edx` to 3 also prints nothing.

Comment: If you are on a 64-bit system, you will need to assemble and link as 32-bit code for this to work.

Comment: Right: use `gcc -m32`.