# Why doesn't pushing a character to the stack without an explicit nul-char look like an underfined behaviour?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, undefined-behavior, stack-memory

The following snippet comes from the [lesson 7 on asmtutor.com](https://asmtutor.com/#lesson7) :

```
;------------------------------------------
; void sprintLF(String message)
; String printing with line feed function
sprintLF:
    call    sprint
 
    push    eax         ; push eax onto the stack to preserve it while we use the eax register in this function
    mov     eax, 0Ah    ; move 0Ah into eax - 0Ah is the ascii character for a linefeed
    push    eax         ; push the linefeed onto the stack so we can get the address
    mov     eax, esp    ; move the address of the current stack pointer into eax for sprint
    call    sprint      ; call our sprint function
    pop     eax         ; remove our linefeed character from the stack
    pop     eax         ; restore the original value of eax before our function was called
    ret                 ; return to our program
```

`sprint` is a subroutine that executes an equivalent of `strlen` on the string pointed to by `eax` and then uses the obtained result to perform a write with the whole string. The purpose of the subroutine from this snippet is to perform an sprint but also systematically print a newline feed by pushing a `0Ah` on the stack and then performing a `sprint` on `esp` (after a `mov eax, esp`).

But putting a nul-character after the `0Ah` on the stack wasn't explicitly made. And yet, `sprint` will rely on a `strlen` to know the size to pass to the `write` syscall.

**question :**

Is it normal to not explicitly put a nul-char after the linefeed character on the stack? And how is it not a segfault risk/undefined behaviour (as I'd fear the `strlen` to not stop without nul-char and thus causing problems)?

Comment: `push eax` is a 4-byte `push`, of `0x0000000A` which has 3 bytes of zeros.  `push 0Ah` would do the same thing with fewer instructions, but `push eax` makes the dword operand-size explicit.  You could make it even more explicit in the source code by writing `mov eax, 000Ah` if you want.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of [Print newline with as little code as possible with NASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57001872) but it does discuss the fact that `push 0Ah` would sign-extend an 8-bit immediate to produce terminating zeros.

Comment: [Assembly program to write character from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48327001) has the opposite goal, of multiple 1-byte pushes *not* having zero bytes between them, but the answer shows a stack diagram which perfectly answers this question.

Comment: @PeterCordes These comments of yours answer my question. Thank you.